# Content displayed on a connected screen is not showed in full screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When testing my app in a real device connected to a tv or monitor by hdmi cable, the content that is showed in the connected screen is not showed in full screen.

**In a real device with a real connected screen:**
[image]

I have tested my app in the iOS Simulator with the simulated connected screen and everything works great.

**In the iOS Simulator:**
[image]

I have tested my app in different kinds of screens and the content in the connected screen is never showed in full screen when using real devices.

I have also tested [this example](https://github.com/andymuncey/swift-external-screen-demo) having the same results.

This is part of the code:

```
if UIScreen.screens.count > 1 {
    let secondScreen = UIScreen.screens[1]
    secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: secondScreen.bounds)
    secondWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    secondWindow.screen = secondScreen

    let secondScreenView = UIView(frame: secondWindow.frame)
    secondWindow.addSubview(secondScreenView)
    secondWindow.isHidden = false

    secondScreenView.backgroundColor = .purple

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: secondScreenView.bounds)
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: recursoTipoRecurso.recurso.contenido as Data)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

    secondScreenView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

As showed in the previous images there is a space between the monitor screen border and the content I set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that this is an issue with your monitor more so than the code...

Comment: I have tried my app in different monitors and tv, and I have the same problem in all of them. The Keynote app actually shows content in fullscreen mode.

Comment: So you can try pinning the view's constraints with superView's constraints instead of safe area's constraints.

Comment: @KazMiller - where you called this code , in viewdidload or else

Comment: This is because the screen ratio is different in different devices and it will change accordingly. You can change the contendMode of the image to cover the full screen but it will make the images stretch

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm interested in it. same problem here.

Comment: @Creanomy Not yet. Sorry

Comment: @KazMiller, no problem... I go on looking for a solution, I'll let you know if I find something interesting.

Comment: @KazMiller, I posted something interesting... Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue with the app/code, it's an issue of the screen ratio. While connecting it to the external screen the monitor keep the iPad screen ratio. The only way is to manually change the size of the content on the monitor itself by stretching it. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: but the content is showed in full screen when using the Keynote app or playing videos without changing the monitor sctetch

Answer (score 1):

Set your second screen with `overscanCompensation` to `.none` will certainly help. It did for me.

```
let secondScreen = UIScreen.screens[1]
secondScreen.overscanCompensation = .none
```

[Apple Dev Definition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617818-overscancompensation)

Comment: Thank you!  This was what was keeping mine from reaching the edges of the screen.